# clang complete doesn't work

Tags: vim, clang, clang-complete

I installed clang_complete for vim,but it doesn't work. For example: When I typed `std::` in a c++ file with vim, the bottom of vim's window shows that:

```
User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you need to provide more detail about your setup if you want to get any useful help.  But probably clang_complete can't find clang in your path.

Comment: How did you install it? What the configuration about clang complete in you vimrc? Can you add these information to your question please.

Answer (score 5):

The common solution to this appears to be to add:

```
let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0'
```

to your .vimrc file.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was solved at the issue [#178](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/pull/178). This was in truth a problem with Clang, I've opened a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13616) and it was promptly solved.

Also, I invite you to take a look at [my setup](http://oblita.com/blog/2012/08/30/vim-the-killer/).